# Writing addresses of more than one authors in a research paper

Tags: author

I want to write addresses of more than one authors in a research paper written in tex format, with a specific requirement: I want to put on top right of author's names the numbers 1 and 2; and at the end, I want to indicate by 1 and 2, the addresses of corresponding authors. (I hope this is clear to you what I want.)

I was able to write *without this requirement* as below. With the requirement, how should we modify it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[letterpaper, body={14.6cm, 23.4cm}, mag=1000]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\title{Physics}
\author{Newton, Einstein}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Newton's first law of motion.
$E=mc^2$.

\end{document}

\newcommand{\Addresses}{{
\footnotesize 

Newton 
\noindent  {\sc Cambridge University} \textit{E-mail address: } 
\texttt{newton@gmail.com}

Einstein 
\noindent  {\sc Oxford University } \textit{E-mail address: },  
\texttt{einstein@yahoo.com}

 }}

\noindent\Addresses
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\thanks` to provide author contact information in footnotes.
You can define commands to hold the authors' addresses, and you can define a separate command that will format them all the same way.

Generally, if you find yourself writing explicit formatting commands, especially if you are doing this repeatedly, you'll be getting the most out of LaTeX if you abstract these into commands.

`\textsc` and `\textit` are now the correct LaTeX commands. Also, since e-mail addresses can have special characters that will cause problems, it's safer to use `\url` from the `url` package from the e-mail addresses.

```
documentclass{article}                                                                                               
\usepackage{url}                                                                                                      
\newcommand{\authoraddress}[2]{%                                                                                      
    \textsc{#1} \textit{E-mail address:} \protect\url{#2}%                                                            
}                                                                                                                     
\newcommand{\NewtonAddress}{                                                                                          
    \authoraddress{Cambridge University}{newton@example.com}%                                                         
}                                                                                                                     
\newcommand{\EinsteinAddress}{%                                                                                       
    \authoraddress{Oxford University}{einstein@example.com}%                                                          
}                                                                                                                     

\title{Physics}                                                                                                       
\author{Newton\thanks{\NewtonAddress}, Einstein\thanks{\EinsteinAddress}}                                             

\begin{document}                                                                                                      
\maketitle                                                                                                            

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is the default in LaTeX for the `\thanks` notes to use symbols instead of numbers, so as not to conflict with regular numbered footnotes. This can be overridden, but it's complicated.